# Who has laid down the English poetry rules?

Tags: poetry, conventions, rules, rhythm

I am doing a research, I want to know who has invented the English poetry rules like meters (Iambic, Torchee, ...) and feets; who has discovered that some feet are (Stressed, Unstressed) and others are (Unstressed, Stressed)

You may provide me by a resource so that I can investigate more.

Comment: There aren't any "rules" for English poetry. Different terms to describe what people have done, such as 'iambic pentameter' have been made up or adapted over time as they were needed. Rhythm in words pre-dates English by a long time.

Comment: Ok, where did "Iambic, Torchee, .." come from?!

Comment: Iambic: 1580 according to the OED.

Comment: Does this mean that English poems are described by the Greek prosody tools?

Comment: Greek prosody, as far as I know, uses quite complex rules about stress that don't directly relate to syllables as we know them. What I know about English comes from the OED (The Oxford English Dictionary) a multi-volume (if it is printed) tome that I usually access online to trace the origins of words.

Comment: Not enough for an answer, IMHO, but I'd start with Aristiotle, including *The Poetics*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research project, huh, Taha? :)

Well you can't beat a bit of eclectic searching on the internet for that kind of thing.

Here's a wonderful (and succinct) page I found on the web that offers a starter-for-ten: http://www.improve-education.org/id49.html

Here's what I'd do:

- go to that link
- read what's written
- use the names there as a basis for further search and research
- own everything you read by adding your own style to what you understand
- Have fun as you do it. :)

Comment: I have to read a lot then :"D
Thank You so much.

Comment: Huh! Which sorry person just voted down the accepted answer and the only one that was given to this question?! Nice for what.